# Is there a way to copy a rectangular area in a bash or konsole terminal?

Tags: bash, clipboard, konsole

Is there a way to copy a rectangular area in a bash or konsole terminal?

Is something like this supported on the normal terminal, or will it be only available on terminals run in a GUI environment?

Comment: Copy what? The text or a screenshot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select a column of text in konsole by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> while selecting with the mouse.